# How can I find the free app of the day?

Tags: mac-appstore, price

I'm a Mac user. I want to know which software will help me find the free app of the day in the App Store?

App store always lists the free apps, but it doesn’t display the original price of the applications.

Answer (score 5):

I use [Store News](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/store-news/id416323139) which is excellent for finding out price drops and discounted apps.

If you have an iOS device, try [AppZapp](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appzapp/id383151779?mt=8) - allows you to set watch lists, and push notifications and has the ability to track Mac Apps too.

Answer (score 2):

[AppShopper](http://appshopper.com/mac) is my personal favorite . Notifies you change of version bumps and price changes if the item is in your **Want** list.

Comment: i think we didn't need version bump? App Store can do itself right?